# Return value from class function

Tags: jquery, class, control-flow

I'm trying to build a class of custom alerts, based on Boostrap. Everything is still very young but I encountered a problem. How can I return a value according to the clicked button only when the click event happens? Here you can see how I set the value (very easy, for tests)

```
    $modal.on('click', '[data-alertify="cancel"]', function(){
        var value = 'no';
        $modal.modal('hide');
        return value;
    });
    $modal.on('click', '[data-alertify="confirm"]', function(){
        var value = 'yes';
        $modal.modal('hide');
        return value;
    });
```

Here is my class and test code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YuriJF/eqLuq6mj/1/)

As you can see, the alert (obviously) appears before the modal is shown. How should I handle this? How can I wait for the correct value to be returned, and then alert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that these callback functions are called asynchronously, and the value returned by the `return` statements therein are not available to you afterwards. The following construct would only work if the whole process were synchronous:

```
var ret = Alertify.alert({
   content: 'This is MY alert content!'
});
```

... but `Alertify.alert()` does not return the desired value, since the user has not yet clicked. This `alert()` function does not return anything, and could certainly not return the result of a click that still has to happen.

This scenario is ideal for introducing promises. This is how it looks when you do that:

First change the `showModal` function to return a promise:

```
var showModal = function (alert_id) {
  $('body').append($html);
  var $modal = $('#' + alert_id);
  $modal.modal('show');
  var dfd = $.Deferred(); // create a promise
  $modal.on('click', '[data-alertify="cancel"]', function(){
    var value = 'no';
    $modal.modal('hide');
    dfd.resolve(value); // instead of returning the value, resolve the promise with it
  });
  $modal.on('click', '[data-alertify="confirm"]', function(){
    var value = 'yes';
    $modal.modal('hide');
    dfd.resolve(value);
  });
  $modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).remove();
    dfd.resolve();
  });
  return dfd.promise(); // return the (unresolved) promise
};
```

Now `Alertify.alert` will return a promise object, which exposes a `then` method, to which you pass a callback:

```
Alertify.alert({
  content: 'This is MY alert content!'
}).then(function(ret) {
   alert(ret);
});
```

... and that's it.

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqLuq6mj/2/).

Comment: why are the `on` callbacks called asynchronously?

Comment: Because they are triggered by a user click, and this happens when your code is already done running.

Comment: I knew I had to deal with promises, I was just guessing if there is another way of doing it. Would it be possible to return the value into a variable, without using `$.then()`? For example `var ret_value=Alertify.prompt(.....);` so that my code would appear cleaner?

Comment: @Yuri, no that is not possible, since that requires you get the return value synchronously, i.e. immediately. Note that the native `prompt` and `alert` methods in the browser context are ugly exceptions to this rule, since those methods completely block the browser. Although it is technically possible to mimic this with a busy loop -- which would indeed lock up your browser -- this is considered (very!) bad practice.